# displaying listview data in android toast

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

i have a list view with a button and a bunch of data(name,age,height of people) one element of the listview is for each person's data. I want to be able to create a toast when the button is clicked, displaying the person's name. The data for the people is stored in a 
arrayList of objects that i created. how can this be done? The problem im having is access the data in the onclicklistener  onclick function

Answer (score 2):

in your getView method you have to set setOnClickListener and then getPosition of clicked item and use it to get information from your arraylist that hold data, then call getName() (or some function that return you tha name) and display it ...

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textViewRow);
                holder.button = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + yourArrayList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }


private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
                    Button button;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code getters and setters in the class whose objects you are using in your list. Add an OnClickListener for the button in each row in the getView method of your list and then use the position and the get method to display the persons name.

For example-

```
ArrayList<PersonData> list = new ArrayList<PersonData>();
```

Add getters and setters in the PersonData class, and then to get the persons name, the button's OnClickListener can be coded in the getView method as-

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"" + list.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        });
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. I missed that somehow. In that case, add an OnClickListener for your button in the getView method and the rest of it stays pretty much the same as Matej has explained.I'll edit my answer.